# On the equality of integrals over the unit disc

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

So I was faced with the following problem in a real analysis test:

> Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $z \in \mathbb R^n$ a fixed vector. Prove that 
>   $$\int_D f(\langle x,z\rangle) dx = \int_D f(x_n|z|)dx$$
>   where D is the closed unit disc $D= \{x \in \mathbb R^n; |x| \leq 1\}$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the cannonical inner product of $\mathbb R^n$.

I'm not sure I believe the statement, as I can't get any grasp on what exactly it means besides that the two integrals are the same. Is there a nice geometric interpretation of this equality? It just feels away to arbitrary for me right now, I don't have any intuition as to why this should hold.

I've also tried to ignore any geometric meaning behind it and just work my away around the integrals so I could find a proof of the statement, but I did get anywhere, so any solutions would also be much appreciated.

Comment: The idea is that it depends only on $|z|$, i.e., it's a radial function of $z.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: If $T$ is an orthogonal transformation on $\mathbb R^n,$ then $\langle u,v \rangle= \langle Tu,Tv \rangle$ for all $u,v \in \mathbb R^n.$ Furthermore, if $g$ is continuous on $D$ and $T$ is orthogonal, then

$$\int_D g(x)\,dx = \int_D g(T(x))\,dx.$$

Comment: So if I choose an orthogonal ordered basis with the last vector being $z/|z|$ the change of basis would be the orthogonal transformation that does the trick, right?

Comment: @DouglasFinamore Not exactly,. You want to choose $T$ such that $T(z) = |z|e_n.$

Comment: Yes, that would be the inverse of the transformation I first thought, I noticed that once I sat down to write a proper answer to the exercise. Now, I'm not sure I understood how being a radial function of $z$ played a role in all this, though now I have this impression that geometrically the change of variables is somewhat projecting $x$ in the $z$-axis. Would you care to elaborate on your first comment?

Comment: @DouglasFinamore I mentioned "radial" to address your "I'm not sure I believe the statement ..." paragraph. It played no role in the proof.